# Remove filename from URL with Express

Tags: node.js, express, web

When I host my front-end on Nodejs, I use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`. However, this makes me put the name of the HTML file at the end of the URL; for example, localhost:3000/index.html.

How would I make it show the front-end at the base URL, in this case, "localhost:3000/". I have attached a part of my Nodejs code. I would appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server is ready"));
```

Comment: So do you use index.html as a front page on backend server?

Comment: what is your front end? is a framework or more html template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a route path and sendFile method:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html", {root: path.join(__dirname, "public")})
})
```

[More details here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do.

```
//for static files like css and html

app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, path to css and js)));


app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path to your html file'))
})
```

Comment: How can I add my Javascript and CSS file to the HTML?

Comment: modified the answer.  It should be folder that holds your css and js files